# NodeMcu V3 & BMe280 -> Temperature, Humidity, Pressure: value nan

Tags: esp8266, sensors, nodemcu, temperature-sensor

I've just started playing around with a NodeMcu V3 and a [BME280 sensor](https://www.ebay.it/itm/173602844579?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=zP2vxbj4Rpe&sssrc=4429486&ssuid=P9XaWv98RhG&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY).

[image]

wiring

```
VCC -> 3.3V
GND -> GND
SCL -> D1 (GPIO5)
SDA -> D2 (GPIO4)
```

I've tried this sketch /  I2C scanner: it finds the BME280 at 0x76

```
#include <Wire.h>

// Set I2C bus to use: Wire, Wire1, etc.
#define WIRE Wire

void setup() {
  WIRE.begin();

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
     delay(10);
  Serial.println("\nI2C Scanner");
}


void loop() {
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;

  Serial.println("Scanning...");

  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ ) 
  {
    // The i2c_scanner uses the return value of
    // the Write.endTransmisstion to see if
    // a device did acknowledge to the address.
    WIRE.beginTransmission(address);
    error = WIRE.endTransmission();

    if (error == 0)
    {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address<16) 
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(address,HEX);
      Serial.println("  !");

      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error==4) 
    {
      Serial.print("Unknown error at address 0x");
      if (address<16) 
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0)
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  else
    Serial.println("done\n");

  delay(5000);           // wait 5 seconds for next scan
}
```

Then I've tried library BMx280I2C into this sketch:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <BMx280I2C.h>


BMx280I2C bmx280(0x76);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Setup BMx280
  Wire.begin();
  bmx280.begin();
  bmx280.resetToDefaults();
  bmx280.writeOversamplingPressure(BMx280I2C::OSRS_P_x16);
  bmx280.writeOversamplingTemperature(BMx280I2C::OSRS_T_x16);
  bmx280.writeOversamplingHumidity(BMx280I2C::OSRS_H_x16);

}

void loop() {

  // T,P,H measurements
  bmx280.measure();

  do{
    delay(100);
    Serial.println("No value, yet!");
  } while (!bmx280.hasValue());

  Serial.print("Pressure ");
  Serial.println(bmx280.getPressure());

  Serial.print("Temperature ");
  Serial.println(bmx280.getTemperature());

  Serial.print("Humidity ");
  Serial.println(bmx280.getHumidity());

  delay(1000);
  
}
```

the output is always and only:

> ```
> -> No value, yet!
> -> Pressure nan
> -> Temperature nan
> -> Humidity nan
> ```

Why? How can I understand the origin of the problem?Thanks!

Comment: Did you run the [BMx280_I2C example sketch](https://github.com/christandlg/BMx280MI/blob/master/examples/BMx280_I2C/BMx280_I2C.ino)? Did it function correctly>

Comment: For [ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Wire/Wire.h#L56), you need to call `Wire.begin(D2, D1);` or `Wire.begin(4, 5);` instead of just `Wire.begin()`.

Comment: @hcheung set  Wire.begin(D2,D1); but same behaviour

Comment: The `begin()` method on `BMx280I2C ` returns an indication of whether it succeeds or not. You should check it. Also CSB should be connected to VCC to force the I2C interface.

Comment: @StarCat same result

21:31:30.943 -> Pressure: nan
21:31:30.943 -> Pressure (64 bit): nan
21:31:30.977 -> Temperature: nan
21:31:30.977 -> Humidity: nan

Comment: With this libary https://github.com/Erriez/ErriezBMX280 (example in the same page) I obtain values! But are always the same... For example always Temperature: -142.46

Comment: Do you check for errors when you use that library? The code you posted doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with [Adafruit library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/adafruit-bme280-library/)

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

Adafruit_BME280 bme;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  if (!bme.begin(0x76)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readTemperature());
  Serial.println(" *C");

  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readHumidity());
  Serial.println(" %");

  Serial.print("Pressure = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readPressure() / 100.0F);
  Serial.println(" hPa");

  Serial.print("Approx. Altitude = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA));
  Serial.println(" m");

  Serial.println();

  delay(2000);
}
```